# BackboneJS How to pass a value between modules

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I want to display a list of artists based on the letter users can click on an alphabet. But somehow, even though the letter is passed, I get an error e.g. it says the letter is undefined despite the fact my console.log gives me the correct letter. Here is what I did sofar:

My artistsAll.js module:

```
var ArtistsAll = App.module();
var ArtistsAllView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName : 'li',
  template: 'artistItem',
  serialize: function() {
    return this.model.toJSON();
  }
});

ArtistsAll.View = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName  : 'ul',
  className : 'artistList',
  initialize: function() {
    this.collection.on('sync', _.bind(this.render, this));          
  },
  beforeRender: function() {
    var self = this;    
    this.collection.each(function(item) {
        self.insertView(new ArtistsAllView({model: item}))
    })
  }     
});

ArtistsAll.ArtistsAllCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: function() {
    return App.APIO + '/i/search/artist?name=' + this.letter; 
  }
});

return ArtistsAll;
```

Basically, there is an endpoint for each letter, for example `/i/search/artist?name=b`

Then, in my controller I have:

```
var ArtistsAllModule = require('modules/artistsAll');

ArtistController.prototype.initArtistLetter = function(letter) {
   this.artistsAllCollection = new ArtistsAllModule.ArtistsAllCollection();
   this.artistsAllCollection.letter = letter;
   App.useLayout('artistLetter', 'artistLetter').setViews({
      '.artistsDiv': new ArtistsAllModule.View({collection: this.artistsAllCollection});
   }).render();     
   this.artistsAllCollection.fetch();
};
```

All I get, is empty page, no errors.... can someone tell me what the issue is here?

Comment: i see few issues 1) u set `letter` on init as `ArtistController.artistsAllCollection` in proto, later override it with `ArtistsAll.ArtistsAllCollection = Backbone`. 2) `this` inside Backbone.Collection is not `ArtistController`. If i were u i would create common MessageBus (request/response) to communicate between modules, like in Marionette JS

Comment: Ok sorry, didnt get you at all :-/

Comment: where is the console.log call you mention?

Comment: When I console.log(letter) it gives me the correct letter, but I always get `/i/search/artist?name=undefined` OR `/i/search/artist?name=[object Object]` :-/

Comment: Anyone? Why does `this.letter` get returned as an object?

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your code like the following:

```
ArtistsAll.View = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName  : 'ul',
  className : 'artistList',
  initialize: function() {
    // here's the modification
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render, this); // but where's your render function!
  },
```

Comment: lack of a render function is the main problem here

Comment: but where's your render function?